# Need to convert SQL to complicated Linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

I need to convert this SQL to Linq I dont' know how..

```
 INSERT INTO @retCluster (HCIS_ID)
 SELECT HCIS_ID FROM OHCD_EmployeeInfo 
 WHERE ImmediateSupervisor IN (SELECT HCIS_ID FROM @retCluster)
 AND HCIS_ID NOT IN (SELECT HCIS_ID FROM @retCluster)
 AND HCIS_Status_ID = 1
```

Comment: So how is your temp table `@retCluster` populated?

Answer (score 1):

LINQ does not support inserting records in your database.
As the name says is for Query purposes only (right now); You cannot delete, update or insert. You need to rely on a `DbContext` or `ObjectContext` (EF) or `DataContext` (L2S) tables functionality to execute these operations on the tables mapped to your database after you have pulled the entities from the database.

There are extensions to entity framework that allow lambda based functionality to execute update or delete commands by passing expressions.

Also in your case, your Context needs to have knowledge about the variable table `@retCluster` which is not possible. You can still use `DbContext.Database.SqlQuery` method to execute any string based command in your database using the DbContext connection.